# Need sed help deleting 2nd and 3rd to last column

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to use sed to change the following lines

```
rec.autos.sport.f1 0000001427 0000000001 y
rec.autos.sport.misc 0000000177 0000000001 y
rec.music.bluenote.blues 0000000531 0000000001 y
sci.med.transcription 0000000187 0000000001 m
test.test.222 0000000000 00001 m
```

into this

```
addgroup rec.autos.sport.f1 y
addgroup rec.autos.sport.misc y
addgroup rec.music.bluenote.blues y
addgroup sci.med.transcription m
addgroup test.test.222 m
```

I got the addgroup part down with

```
s/\(^[a-zA-Z]\)/addgroup \1/g
```

I'm new to using sed so I have no idea how to achieve this. If anyone answers a quick explanation of what you did would help a lot.

Comment: `s/^\([^[:blank:]]\+\)[[:blank:]]\([^[:blank:]]\+[[:blank:]]\)\{2\}\(.*\)$/addgroup \1 \3/g`

Answer (score 0):

#### Using sed

Adding a second substitute command after yours:

```
$ sed -e 's/\(^[a-zA-Z]\)/addgroup \1/' -e 's/\( [^[:blank:]][^[:blank:]]*\)\{2\}\( [^[:blank:]]*\)$/\2/g' file
addgroup rec.autos.sport.f1 y
addgroup rec.autos.sport.misc y
addgroup rec.music.bluenote.blues y
addgroup sci.med.transcription m
addgroup test.test.222 m
```

Or, combining it all into one `s` command:

```
$ sed -e 's/\(.*\)\( [^[:blank:]][^[:blank:]]*\)\{2\}\( [^[:blank:]][^[:blank:]]*\)$/addgroup \1 \3/g' file
addgroup rec.autos.sport.f1  y
addgroup rec.autos.sport.misc  y
addgroup rec.music.bluenote.blues  y
addgroup sci.med.transcription  m
addgroup test.test.222  m
```

With extended regular expressions, we can avoid all those backslashes.  Using GNU sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*)( [^[:blank:]]+){2}( [^[:blank:]]+)$/addgroup \1 \3/g' file
addgroup rec.autos.sport.f1  y
addgroup rec.autos.sport.misc  y
addgroup rec.music.bluenote.blues  y
addgroup sci.med.transcription  m
addgroup test.test.222  m
```

#### Using GNU awk

The OP asked for sed.  For those who are curious, though, here is a GNU awk solution:

```
$ awk '{$(NF-2)=$NF; NF-=2; printf "addgroup %s\n",$0;} ' file
addgroup rec.autos.sport.f1 y
addgroup rec.autos.sport.misc y
addgroup rec.music.bluenote.blues y
addgroup sci.med.transcription m
addgroup test.test.222 m
```

Answer (score 0):

another awk solution with `tr` to normalize white space

```
awk '{$1="addgroup "$1;$2=$3=""}1' file | tr -s ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]\+\)[ 0-9]\+\(.\)$/addgroup \1 \2/'
```